# Label não atualiza através do setText no JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, label

Boa noite,

Estou com um problema ao tentar alterar o texto de umas label's através do método sexText e não consigo identificar o problema, agradeço a ajuda. Código:

```
void atualizar()
{

    lbStatusPlatao.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(0).toString());
    lbStatusSocrates.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(1).toString());
    lbStatusRousseau.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(2).toString());
    lbStatusMarx.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(3).toString());
    lbStatusAristoteles.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(4).toString());


    if(jantar.statusGarfo(0))
    {
        statusGarfo1.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        statusGarfo1.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
    }

    if(jantar.statusGarfo(1))
    {
        statusGarfo2.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        statusGarfo2.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
    }

    if(jantar.statusGarfo(2))
    {
        statusGarfo3.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        statusGarfo3.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
    }

    if(jantar.statusGarfo(3))
    {
        statusGarfo4.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        statusGarfo4.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
    }

    if(jantar.statusGarfo(4))
    {
        statusGarfo5.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        statusGarfo5.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);
    }
}

@FXML
void comecarJantar(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException 
{
    jantar.criarFilosofos(cbDeadlock.isSelected());
    jantar.iniciar();

    Task<Void> taskAtualizacao = new Task<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                atualizar();
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread atualizador = new Thread(taskAtualizacao);
    atualizador.start();
}

@FXML
void pararJantar(ActionEvent event) 
{
    jantar.parar();
}
```

Exceções geradas:

> Gtk-Message: 02:52:19.263: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
>   Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
>       at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
>       at controller.MesaController.atualizar(MesaController.java:58)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:124)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:1)
>       at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
>       at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
>       at controller.MesaController.atualizar(MesaController.java:59)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:124)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:1)
>       at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
>       at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
>       at controller.MesaController.atualizar(MesaController.java:60)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:124)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:1)
>       at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
>       at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
>       at controller.MesaController.atualizar(MesaController.java:61)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:124)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:1)
>       at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
>       at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
>       at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
>       at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
>       at controller.MesaController.atualizar(MesaController.java:62)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:124)
>       at controller.MesaController$1.call(MesaController.java:1)
>       at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você ler sua exceção, vai ver que a mensagem é "Not on FX application thread". Isso ocorreu porque seu setText() foi chamado em uma thread diferente daquela onde a aplicação JavaFX está executando. Então o que o Java está te dizendo é que você só pode alterar propriedades de elementos do JavaFX a partir da thread principal, ou seja, aquela onde a aplicação está rodando. É fácil resolver isso. Altere aquele trecho do seu código para:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    lbStatusPlatao.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(0).toString());
    lbStatusSocrates.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(1).toString());
    lbStatusRousseau.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(2).toString());
    lbStatusMarx.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(3).toString());
    lbStatusAristoteles.setText(jantar.statusFilosofo(4).toString());
});
```

Assim você está dizendo para sua aplicação JavaFX executar, assim que possível, suas alterações.

Comment: Muito obrigado, solucionou, valeu, eu não sabia que uma Thread externa não possui permissão pra alterar componentes do JavaFX, estou começando com a API agora, muito obrigado pela informação e pela ajuda